# PGFPlots skip color in standard color scheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I skip a color in the standard color scheme of a pgfplot?
It would be even better to pick colors.

I've tried to use `index of colormap` as in following example: **EDIT**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[index of colormap=1] coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1.5) (1,1)};
\addplot[index of colormap=2] coordinates {(0,2) (0.5,2.5) (1,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image: result]

I want the first line to be red and the second to be brown (as these are the second and the third color of the standard coloring scheme). Also the markers are missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The `index of colormap` index is starting with `0` ...

Comment: I know. In the example above the first line should have the second color of the standard scheme. That's why `index of colormap=1`

Comment: Then please edit your question and replace your code with a complete MWE starting with `\documentclass` so we can reproduce the problem. Please also replace your CSV file with some dummy data so *we* can also TeX/compile your document.

Comment: that can simply be done by adding `\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}` before the first `\addplot` command and removing the optional arguments (in `[...]`) of the `\addplot` commands. ...

Comment: ... `[index of colormap]` uses - as the name states - the colors of the `colormap` which by default is `hot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}` works in this example. But what if i want to pick  a abitrary color of the standard color scheme? For example I have multiple plots. In all plots I have a line for the lets say CPU. I want this line to always be black, no mather how many lines are in the plot. Does this work?

Comment: Great. Do you think it is worth that I post a complete answer or do you want to delete your question?

Comment: I have a further question. see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45919/discussion-between-stefan-pinnow-and-martin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already stated in the comments to change the (actual) index of the `cycle list` one has to use the key `cycle list shift` *before* each `\addplot` command where the index should be changed.

(And without any more options given also the markers are/should be plotted.)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
                % shift the index of the cycle list by ...
                \pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=1}
            \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1.5) (1,1)};
            \addplot coordinates {(0,2) (0.5,2.5) (1,2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]